# Parse, force upDatedAt to update

Tags: parse-platform

I have a PFObject Conversation that is pointed to by Messages.  I would like to organize my tableView by last updated conversation.  When I create a message, I set a pointer, parent, to a conversation.  I have tried saving the conversation also, but its upDatedAt does not change; Im guessing because it didn't actually change.  Is there a way I can force it to "update," or should I just create my own property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered your own question, you would have to create your own field with a date value to keep track of when the last message was sent in a conversation.

As far as I know, manually setting created/updatedAt is not supported at the moment and thinking about it further, it probably would be bad idea to allow this as the format of that field might change over time, breaking many apps that still use the old "format" and set this field to an incorrect/unsupported value.

Another idea for this is to create a 'messagesSent' counter field to update the number of messages each time one is sent, this should update the built in updatedAt field and also has the nice side-effect that you don't need to make a possibly expensive and in-accurate count query if you decided to display the number of messages a conversations contains.

Comment: Ya I like the counter idea.  I think I'll probably do that.  In the future, it might be nice to add a label with message count and that would be perfect. I knew updatedAt/createdAt were readonly, but I thought saving the conversation, even without changing it, would change the updatedAt. I guess it only actually saves dirty data, which would make more sense anyways.  Thank you.

Comment: That is correct, it only updates and saves if the object actually is dirty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the accepted answer is still accurate. I'm working on a server monitoring tool which sends application-level pings on a regular basis, so on the front-end I have something which tells the user when the last ping was sent. To do this, I'm querying for all the servers, and then pinging all of the applications associated with each server. The below is a representation of what I did:

```
let query = new Parse.Query(Server)
query.find()
.then(servers => {
  servers.forEach(server => {
    server.save() // this is where I updated the server's updatedAt

    // ... pingServices(servers)

  })
})
```

I'm fairly sure calling `save` works to update `updatedAt` as it's quite a visible part of the tool that I'm working on.